# how to use angular 1 variables inside the angular 2 component

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-template

***login.js***

```
var app= angular.module('login',[]);

app.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope)
{

$scope.sayhello="Hello"+ $scope.username;

}).directive('loginDir', function(){
 return {
  scope:{},
  templateUrl: 'logintpl.html',
  controller: 'LoginCtrl'
};
});

var adapter = new ng.upgrade.UpgradeAdapter();

AppComponent = ng.core
  .Component({
    selector: 'login',
    directives: [adapter.upgradeNg1Component('loginDir')],
    template: '<login-dir></login-dir>'
    })
  .Class({
    constructor: function() {}
  });

app.directive('login', adapter.downgradeNg2Component(AppComponent));
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  adapter.bootstrap(document.body, ['login']);
  console.log(adapter);
});
```

***logintpl.html***

```
<input type="name" ng-model="username">
```

how can i use $scope.sayhello variable inside the component.

`eg: component template should be,template:'<login-dir></login-dir>{{sayhello}}`

Answer (score 2):

```
AppComponent = ng.core
  .Component({
    selector: 'login',
    directives: [adapter.upgradeNg1Component('loginDir')],
    template: '<login-dir></login-dir> {{sayhello}}'
    })
  .Class({
    constructor: function() {
        this.sayhello = "Hello World !!!";
    }
  });
```

**Explanation**

In Angular 2, there is no model called `$scope`. They replaced it with simple variables with in the `Class`.

We can consider the whole `Class` as a `controller` in Angular 1.x. We can create variable with `this.variable_name` with in a `Class`. `constructor` is the function which will be invoked first in the component. So, we can initialize all our variable here.

So, `$scope.variable_name` in Angular 1.x is same (or likely to) as `this.variable_name` in Angular 2.

Comment: is this sayhello variable similar to the $scope.sayhello variable in directive

Comment: is this.sayhello same as $scope.sayhello

Comment: @BuddhikaKulathilaka yes

Comment: $scope.sayhello=hello username and this.sayhello="hello world". I'm asking is there any way to use $scope.sayhello inside the component

Comment: @BuddhikaKulathilaka, Sorry, I didn't get what you mean. Are you upgrading angular application from 1.x to 2?

Comment: yes.I add new component and I want to use some variables define in directive.

Comment: @BuddhikaKulathilaka, Sorry, I am completely unaware of upgrading process. Sorry, I think I can't help you on this version up-gradation. :(

Answer (score 2):

In fact the `sayhello` attribute can be only used within your `loginDir` directive since it's defined in its associated scope.

You could have a use case like that:

```
app.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.sayhello = function() {
    console.log("Hello"+ $scope.username);
  }
}).directive('loginDir', function() {
  return {
    scope:{},
    templateUrl: 'logintpl.html',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl'
  };
});
```

In the template of your Angular1 directive, you will be able to use this function:

```
<input type="name" ng-model="username">
<span ng-click="sayhello()">Test</span>
```

I don't know what you exactly want to do. Here is the corresponding plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/ribHwk8uSXHRv0JkLlo0?p=preview.

**Edit**

You can have access to attributes of the parent component from the directive since the Angular1 directive scope is internal to your directive. With Angular1, you can't either. The only thing you could do is to define a parameter to your Angular1 directive that corresponds to an attribute of your parent component and update it by reference.

Here is a sample

```
app.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.updateSayhelloInParent = function() {
    console.log("Hello"+ $scope.username);
    $scope.sayhello.message = $scope.username;
  }
}).directive('loginDir', function(){
  return {
    scope:{
      sayhello: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'logintpl.html',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl'
  };
});
```

And the way to use the directive in the component:

```
AppComponent = ng.core
  .Component({
    selector: 'login',
    directives: [adapter.upgradeNg1Component('loginDir')],
    template: `
      <login-dir [sayhello]="sayHello"></login-dir>

      <br/><br/>

      SayHello in component:
      {{sayHello | json}}
    `
    })
  .Class({
    constructor: function() {
      this.sayHello = {
        message: 'default message'
      }
    }
  });
```

Corresponding plunkr is here: https://plnkr.co/edit/ribHwk8uSXHRv0JkLlo0?p=preview.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: i want to know is it possible to use variables in directive inside the component

Comment: if I want to used variable value define in directive inside the component,is it possible

Comment: I don't think so because your scope is internal to your directive. With Angular1, you can't either. The only thing you could do is to define a parameter to your Angular1 directive that corresponds to an attribute of your parent component and update it by reference.

Comment: then if I further write the code using angular 2 is it not possible to use upgraded directive variables with new angular components

Comment: In fact, with Angular2, you can leverage two way bindings for components using custom events. This way you will be able to use something like that: `<login-dir [(sayhello)]="sayHello"></login-dir>`. This way `sayhello` (child component) and `sayHello` (parent component) will be automatically linked and updated accordingly (even for primitive types like string). This can be done internally in the child component using `@Input() sayhello:string` and `@Ouput() sayhelloEvent:EventEmitter`.